# ServiceNow-How to get a record (INCIDENT/REQUEST/CHANGE)

Tags: servicenow

Is there any common URL to navigate to serviceNow portal with number (INC/REQ/CHG)?

I have an common URL (INC/REQ/CHG) which can be navigated to ServiceNow portal by sys_id:

`https://XXXXdev.service-now.com/nav_to.do?uri=task.do?sys_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

I have tried below URLs for incident but it is creating a new record

`XXXXdev.service-now.com/nav_to.do?uri=incident.do?sysparm_order=INC0XXX`

OR

`XXXXdev.service-now.com/nav_to.do?uri=incident.do?number=INC00XXXX`

No problem if there are different URLs for INC, REQ or CHG, I want a URL to see record by giving a number but not with sys_id.

Comment: I have got for INC XXXdev.service-now.com/nav_to.do?uri=incident.do?sysparm_query=number=INC001XX

Comment: Answers : Incident :https://iXXX.service-now.com/incident.do?sys_id=INC0010910
 request item : https://XXX.service-now.com/sc_req_item.do?sys_id=RITM0010372
 change : https://XXX.service-now.com/change_request.do?sys_id=CHG0030673

Comment: also request item : XXX.service-now.com/task.do?sys_id=RITM0010372

Answer (score 6):

From what you have described I believe you want:

```
https://[instance].service-now.com/incident.do?sysparm_query=number=INC1234567
https://[instance].service-now.com/sc_request.do?sysparm_query=number=REQ1234567
https://[instance].service-now.com/change_request.do?sysparm_query=number=CHG1234567
```

Or the catch all

```
https://[instance].service-now.com/task.do?sysparm_query=number=INC1234567
https://[instance].service-now.com/task.do?sysparm_query=number=REQ1234567
https://[instance].service-now.com/task.do?sysparm_query=number=CHG1234567
```

(see https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/helsinki-servicenow-platform/page/use/navigation/concept/c_NavigatingByURL.html)

If you want to keep the outer frames of SN then use the `nav_to.do?uri=` version e.g.

```
https://[instance].service-now.com/nav_to.do?uri=sc_request.do?sysparm_query=number=REQ1234567
```

which is what @[kirk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45038411/3501748) has described.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options depending on what you're trying to do exactly.

**Email**

If you're trying to send this link in an email notification, you can use `${URI_REF}` for the table that the notification is generated on.

This will automatically generate a link to the record.

You can also *dot walk* to another table, for example

- Catalog Task up to the Requested Item `${request_item.URI_REF}`
- Current task up top the parent record `${parent.URI_REF}`

**Calculated**

If you are looking to generate this based on some calculated method you can do this with the *table name* and the *record number*.

```
https://instance.service-now.com/nav_to.do?uri=/table_name.do?sysparm_que‌​ry=number=RECORD_NUMBER
```

For instance for a *Change* record with record number *CHG0000123*

```
https://instance.service-now.com/nav_to.do?uri=/change.do?sysparm_que‌​ry=number=CHG0000123
```

You may also reference a record by using a parent table, though this is more for an interesting note rather than a good practice. *INC*, *REQ*, and *CHG* all inherit from the *Task* table so you could do this.

```
https://instance.service-now.com/nav_to.do?uri=/task.do?sysparm_que‌​ry=number=CHG0000123
```

The drawback to using the parent table is that it won't have all fields and won't have the proper form layout. Mostly just an interesting exercise.

You may also leverage the *text search* and the system will pull up a record that matches the record number.

```
https://instance.service-now.com/nav_to.do?uri=/textsearch.do?sysparm_que‌​ry=number=CHG0000123
```

Note that this works out of the box and you could have configured search to not behave that way.

**Business Rule**

Another method inside of a *Business Rule* is to use the `current.getLink()` method. This will return a URL to the record. If you would like to add to a journal entry, you could use this

```
var currentLink = "[code]<a href='" + current.getLink() + "'>" + current.number + "</a>[/code]";
var journal = gs.getMessage("The new record is {0}", [currentLink]);
gr.work_notes = journalEntry;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initial URI will actually work with a NUMBER (like `INC000001`), assuming that `number` is actually the display field for the table (as it is by default):

https://XXXX.service-now.com/incident.do?sys_id=NUMBER

When you do a `sys_id=` lookup, we first lookup by the `sys_id` column. If it's not found there, we try a lookup on the display value (`number`), which will load the form exactly as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the logic with incident with that i have just tried this Incident XXX.service-now.com/incident.do?sys_id=INC0010910
 request item :XXX.service-now.com/sc_req_item.do?sys_id=RITM0010372
 change : XXX.service-now.com/change_request.do?sys_id=CHG0030673

Comment: you can't use `incident.do?sys_id=INCxxxxxxx` as sys_id expects a 512 bit unique id of the form 0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef.  hence you need to use `sysparm_query=number=INCxxxxxxx`

Comment: @northern-bradley Have you actually tested that it *doesn't* work? See my description as to why it works. If number is the display field, a sys_id=number search *will* retrieve the record.

Comment: Try the same thing with a GlideRecord.get, that works, too: ```var gr = new GlideRecord("incident");
if (gr.get("INC0010910")) ...```

Comment: I have tested this and it did work. So no reason for the downvotes. The link looks something like this: https://{ENVIRONMENT}.service-now.com/{snowPart}.do?sys_id={SnowRequestId}   and        {snowPart} can be 'task.do' for example

Answer (score 0):

`{yourinstance}.service-now.com/nav_to.do?uri=incident.do?sys_id={incidentNumber}`

Replace `incidentNumber` with your incident number .

Comment: you can't use `incident.do?sys_id=INCxxxxxxx` as sys_id expects a 512 bit unique id of the form 0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef.  hence you need to use `sysparm_query=number=INCxxxxxxx`

Comment: Yes you can use `incident.do?sys_id=INCxxxxxxx`. Try it. Yes, sys_id expects a 32 character GUID, but it falls back to querying by display field if what you give it isn't a 32 character GUID.

Comment: @joey, so it does!  i never knew that